# How to add docker compose project in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: docker-compose, jetbrains-ide, rider

Official docs says:

> If no Docker Compose support is configured in the project, you can enable it by right-clicking your project in the Solution Explorer and choosing Add | Docker Compose File

[image: But there is no such item in menu]

Project configured as Console Application (.NET 7) with docker support. Jet Brains Rider 2022.3.2